# Java Thread Pool with a Bounded Queue

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I'm using `java.util.concurrent`'s [`Executors`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class to create a fixed thread pool for running request handlers for a web server:

```
static ExecutorService  newFixedThreadPool(int nThreads)
```

and the description is:

> Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed set of threads operating off a shared **unbounded** queue.

However, I am looking for thread pool implementation which will do the exact same thing, except with a **bounded** queue. Is there such an implementation? Or do I need to implement my own wrapper for the fixed thread pool?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

What you want to do is new your own ExecutorService, probably using [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).  ThreadPoolExecutor has a constructor which takes a BlockingQueue and to get a bounded queue you use for example [ArrayBlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) properly constructed for bounding.  You can also include a [RejectedExecutionHandler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RejectedExecutionHandler.html) in order to determine what to do when your queue is full, or hang on to a reference to the blocking queue and use the offer methods.

Here's a mini example:

```
BlockingQueue<Runnable> linkedBlockingDeque = new LinkedBlockingDeque<Runnable>(
    100);
ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 10, 30,
    TimeUnit.SECONDS, linkedBlockingDeque,
    new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
```

Comment: Do you know why there isn't a "PostingBlocksPolicy" which blocks until the task _can_ be posted? I'd like to ensure the job is (eventually) done, so none of the discard or abort policies work, and CallerRuns doesn't fly because my whole objective in using a (single-threaded)threadpool is to ensure that work is done on a particular, single thread.

Comment: There isn't really, and it would be what one might call "awkward" if you were to implement one because the caller would never have control of the waits.  What you can do however, is call linkedBlockingDequeue.offer(x) directly and take some action on the result.

 while( !linkedBlockingDequa.offer( myRunnable ) ) {
  // wait, or take some action, or throw an exception
 }

Comment: If you have 2 tasks which are blocking - hung and two threads in the pool, if you set queue size as 5 , and add one more task, that task will take a very long time to execute or if  two threads are hung, maybe never

Comment: @AlexPunen Yes.  And?  There are ways to manage that sort of scenario but it's outside of the scope of the question asked.  If you yourself are having that problem post the issue yourself, i'm sure SO will provide :P

Answer (score 7):

Create a [ThreadPoolexecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#ThreadPoolExecutor%28int,%20int,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,%20java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue,%20java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionHandler%29) and pass suitable BlockingQueue implementation in it. for e.g. you can pass in a [ArrayBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html) in the ThreadPoolExecutor constructor to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 6):

I've solved this with a [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) which I use to throttle tasks being submitted to the `ExecutorService`.

Eg:

```
int threadCount = 10;
ExecutorService consumerPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);

// set the permit count greater than thread count so that we 
// build up a limited buffer of waiting consumers
Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(threadCount * 100); 

for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
    semaphore.acquire(); // this might block waiting for a permit 
    Runnable consumer = () -> {
       try {
          doSomeWork(i);
       } finally {
          semaphore.release(); // release a permit 
       }
    };
    consumerPool.submit(consumer);
}
```

Comment: This solution may lead to permit leak. For example, if the future is cancelled before it is effectively executed, semaphore will never be released and one permit is lost forever. The same problem occurs if the task is rejected by the ExecutorService.

Comment: What if the release was placed outside the consumer? say you do: `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> doSomeWork(i), consumerPool).whenCompleteAsync((i, err)->semaphore.release(), consumerPool)`?

Answer (score 4):

When you create a ThreadPoolExecutor you can give it a bounded BlockingQueue and a RejectedExecutionHandler so you can control what happens when the limit is reached.  The default behaviour is to throw a RejectedExecutionException.

You can also define you own thread factory to control the thread names and make them daemon threads.